# Codeigniter user active and deactive.from admin side

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Using `Codeigniter`, I want to activate and deactivate a user from the admin side ; ff user is active, then show that user in front side.

How can I activate and deactivate users?

Here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_details (
  user_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  firstname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  lastname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  profile_image varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  status int(11) NOT NULL,**
  role varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=68 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want a button to click active and deactivate users from the admin side.

[This](http://mostlikers.2my4edge.com/active-intive/) is what I want.

Comment: if you don't understand my question please let me know. :(

Comment: You have narrow your question to be not like "check this link and everything you see program for me, please". You have to try and where you stuck that you post here. Include code you have tried so far. Do you know how it would look like? First solve your problem, than write the code. If you didn't use registration/ACP modules so far, I suggest you that you make some research or watch some tutorials on YT for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way:

First of all, add a column to your table called `isActive`.

Make a link for each items for this url

In view:

```
echo '<a href="example.com/ctrlName/functionName/?user_id="'.$user_id."&active=1>Active</a>"';
```

In contoller:

```
$active = $this->input->get("active");
if($active == 1){
$this->load->model("db_user");
$this->db_user->activate($user_id);
```

In Model:

```
public function activate($user_id){
$this->db->query("UPDATE users SET isActive = 1 
                  WHERE user_id =?", array($user_id));
}
```

For `Inactivate` in the view, just check if it's already actived or not. (by retrieving column `isActive` from database.

As @Tpojka said in comment, you should see some tutorials.

Comment: Thanks @vahid for the answer.can you give me link for tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the comment its helps alot :)

Comment: @sanju glad to help you. phpacademy is a very useful and complete source for developing php applications and codeigniter framework. Check here https://www.youtube.com/user/phpacademy

Comment: Also I recommend , if you have time, work with laravel framework instead. Best regards :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to do following process:

1. Put one button in each row of `user`.`onclick` of that button make *ajax* call on one *controller*.
2. Pass new status like if current status is 'active' then on click pass 'deactivate' to that controller.also pass user id to that controller.
3. Call proper *model* and create proper query with user id and status.
4. if query executes properly return success to controller and browser.
5. Reload Page.